# requirejs no longer loads cdn scripts after optimization

Tags: requirejs

I'm struggling to get requirejs to work after [optimizing](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty) with r.js
It works fine pre optimization
I'm following the docs for configuring main.js and the build profile using `empty:`
However after optimization, CDN scripts are no longer loaded.

**public/index.html**

```
<script data-main="editor/js/main" src="editor/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
```

**public/editor/js/main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "/editor/js",
  paths: {
      "jquery": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min",
      "order": "vendor/require_order",
      "underscore": "vendor/underscore",
      "handlebars": "vendor/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.4",
      "jquery.mobile.router": "vendor/jquery.mobile.router",
      "jquery.mobile": "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min"
  }
});
require(["order!jquery", "order!underscore", "order!handlebars", "order!jam", "order!jquery.mobile"], function () {
  //loaded
});
```

**config/build.js**

```
({
  baseUrl: "../public/editor/js",
  name: "main",
  out: "../public/editor/js/main-built.js",
  paths: {
      "order": "vendor/require_order",
      "underscore": "vendor/underscore",
      "handlebars": "vendor/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.4",
      "jquery.mobile.router": "vendor/jquery.mobile.router",
      "jquery": "empty:",
      "jquery.mobile": "empty:"
  }
})
```

When I run r.js `node config/r.js -o config/build.js`
main-built.js is built successfully.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm running into a similar problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I abandoned using requireJS, it may be something that has been subsequently fixed. I have not looked at it since February.

Comment: what did you go with? i need optimized dependency mgmt :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you are loading everything using the order plugin?

Were you having load order problems in your built javascript?

If you load jQuery mobile normally (without the plugin) your "empty" configuration should take effect.

```
require(["jquery", "underscore", "handlebars", "jam", "jquery.mobile"], function () {
```

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty

You will also need to define the dependency chain for jQuery.mobile.router

```
requirejs.config({

    paths: {
      "jquery": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min",
      "order": "vendor/require_order",
      "underscore": "vendor/underscore",
      "handlebars": "vendor/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.4",
      "jquery.mobile.router": "vendor/jquery.mobile.router",
      "jquery.mobile": "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min"

    },

    shim: {
        "router": {
            "deps" : ["jquery.mobile"]
        },
        "jquery.mobile" : {
            "deps" : [ "jquery.mobile.router"],
            "exports": "$.mobile" 
        },

        "jquery.mobile.router": {
          "exports": "$.mobile.Router"
        }
    }
});
```

see the answer to this question:

[Require.js with jQueryMobile-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827757/require-js-with-jquerymobile-router)

I hope that resolves your issues with requirejs, I've found it to be a very powerful and useful tool, once you get  used to its structure.

_Pez

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, this question is pretty old, unfortunately I can't recall what I was trying to do for me to answer your question.